# Type Error Issue with React Navigation: "Argument type 'X' is not assignable to parameter type 'any'"

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to use React Navigation to navigate between screens in my React Native application. However, I'm encountering type errors when calling the navigation.navigate function (but that work).

The exact error message I'm receiving is as follows:

`Argument type "Results_page" is not assignable to parameter type any`

and

`Argument type {environment: string, price: string, group: string} is not assignable to parameter type any`

Relevant code:

```
const navigation = useNavigation<SearchTabScreenProps["navigation"]>();
...
navigation.navigate("Results_page", {
  group: group,
  environment: environment,
  price: price,
});
```

Navigation Types:

```
import { NativeStackScreenProps } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import { BottomTabNavigationProp } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";

// ... (definition of RootStackParamList, MainTabParamList)

type SearchTabParamList = {
  Choices_page: undefined;
  Results_page: {
    group: string;
    environment: string;
    price: string;
  };
};

export type RootStackScreenProps = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList>;
export type MainTabScreenProps = BottomTabNavigationProp<MainTabParamList>;
export type SearchTabScreenProps = NativeStackScreenProps<SearchTabParamList>;
```

Navigator Usage:

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<SearchTabScreenProps>();

const Navigator = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
    <Stack.Screen name="Choices_page" component={Choices} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Results_page" component={Results} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);

export default Navigator;
```

I'm curious about the cause of these type errors and how to resolve them properly. Thank you for your assistance!
I have to type with never to remove the warning, but that gets around the problem and isn't a good way to do it.

```
navigation.navigate(
  "Results_page" as never,
   {
    group: group,
    environment: environment,
    price: price,
   } as never,
);
```

I've already tried everything I could find on the internet, but having several navigator (him is not root navigator), the global declaration solution is out of the question.